# Filtro en Template Django

Tags: django

Buenos días tengo mi aplicación en Django 1.10 y Phyton 3, en la cual voy a manejar carnets con fecha de vencimiento para cada uno de los estudiantes. Estos carnets tienen fecha de vencimiento[1], una vez supere la fecha de vencimiento pasaran a estado inactivo. Por lo que pueden llegar a un punto donde varios estudiantes tenga varios carnets asociados pero solo uno activo el resto inactivos.

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar en un template los estudiantes (que se mostraran ya filtrados por grado) y si el estudiante tiene carnet activos que muestre los datos correspondientes al carnet, de lo contrario mostrar en blanco estos campos y un link para asignar el carnet.

**Views.py**

```
def generaCarnet(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.POST['query']
        student = Estudiante.objects.get( numeroDocumento = query )
        grado = Estudiante.objects.filter( grado = student.grado )
        return render(request,'generaCarnet.html',{'grupo':grado,})
    else:
        return render(request,'generaCarnet.html')
```

**template**

```
{% if grupo %}
    <table class="table table-bordered alt">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="active col-sm-1">Documento</td>
                <th class="active col-sm-2">Nombres y apellidos </td>
                <th class="active col-sm-2">Carnet </td>
                <th class="active col-sm-2">Fecha Expedición </td>
                <th class="active col-sm-2">Fecha Vencimiento </td>
                <th class="active col-sm-1">Acción</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for ben in grupo %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ ben.numeroDocumento }}</td>
                    <td>{{ ben.nombreUno|title }} {{ ben.nombreDos|title }} {{ ben.apellidoUno|title }} {{ ben.apellidoDos|title }}</td>
                    {% for carnet in ben.carnet_set.all  %}
                        <td>{{ carnet.codigo }}</td>
                        <td>{{ carnet.fechaExpide }}</td>
                        <td>{{ carnet.fechaVence }}</td>
                        <td><a href="#imprimir" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-print" title="Imprimir" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                        {% empty %}
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><a href="#activar"><i class="fa fa-check" title="Activar" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endif %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Estudiante(models.Model):
    numeroDocumento = models.BigIntegerField()
    apellidoUno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellidoDos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombreUno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombreDos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    grado = models.IntegerField() #Campo en comun entre varios estudiantes

class Carnet(models.Model):
    codigo = models.IntegerField()
    estudiante = models.ForeignKey(Estudiante)
    fechaExpide = models.DateField(null=True)
    fechaVence = models.DateField(null=True)
    estado = models.NullBooleanField(null=True) # Activo o Inactivo del carnet
```

Con lo que tengo hasta ahora me muestra todos los carnets que existen por estudiante y **Solo** quiero que se muestre el carnet **Activo** por estudiante.

[1] Tambien agradeceria si alguien me puede indicar como automatizar al momento que llegue la fecha de vencimiento pase de activo a inactivo el Carnet.

Agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 1):

Para que te muestre solo los activos hay dos formas, o bien en el template filtras:

```
{% for carnet in ben.carnet_set.all  %}
    {% if carnet.activo %}
        ....
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

O en el la consulta te traes solo los carnets activos con el [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related), por ejemplo:

```
grado = Estudiante.objects.filter( grado = student.grado 
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('carnet', queryset=Carnet.objects.filter(activo=True))
     )
```